# При запуске сервера Tomcat 7.0 в eclipse выдает кучу ошибок

Tags: eclipse, java-ee, tomcat

Немогу найти ошибку. Серверный пакет tomcat7.0 перестал загружаться в eclipse.
при создании нового проекта и нового подключения HTML страница загружается, а скрипт загружаться не хочет.
Вот что выводит при загрузке сервера.

```
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:NewWebProject' did not find a matching property.
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:fenix' did not find a matching property.
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Fenix01' did not find a matching property.
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built: Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number: 7.0.75.0
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name: Windows 7
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version: 6.1
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture: amd64
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version: 1.8.0_101-b13
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor: Oracle Corporation
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE: F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=F:\софт\JAVA\Workspace коды файлы программ для работы Eclipse\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1251
мар 19, 2017 1:23:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
мар 19, 2017 1:23:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 19, 2017 1:23:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
мар 19, 2017 1:23:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2384 ms
мар 19, 2017 1:23:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
мар 19, 2017 1:23:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
мар 19, 2017 1:23:18 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [153] milliseconds.
мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fenix]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/fenix]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LOrdersDAO;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:891)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5522)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: OrdersDAO
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
... 20 more

мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 6 more

мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
... 11 more

мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
мар 19, 2017 1:23:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

после ошибок появляется такое окно с надписью

> 'Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>
> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. если можно объяснить, то как можно проще
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вот же `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LOrdersDAO;`

Comment: у меня нету такого класса

Comment: да и на самом проекте горит красная иконка с белым крестиком

Comment: LOrdersDAO; нету ни в одном проекте

Comment: посмотрите все  ли зависимости вы включили в output

Comment: Вопрос как эти зависимости посмотреть есть ли вообще инфа по настройке с указанием таких проблем. Я по инету не нашел

Comment: Почему в новых проектах хтмл загружается а скрипт нет